# Define custom url with AWS presigned url

Tags: amazon-s3, redirect, pre-signed-url, aws-java-sdk

I am migrating our s3 java API from v1 to v2 version.
What I want to do is to generate presigned url. But I want to forge my presigned url because our need is to have a clear url not frightening the user. In our v1 version, we decided to create an url on the format `https://bucket-name/object-key`. then a rule in added in our DNS in order to redirect the request to the AWS server.

In order to achieve so, in v1 version, we created a `s3Client` and override the endpoint configuration with `withEndpointConfiguration` in order to force the domain to https://bucket-name.
Then when we instantiate the GeneratePresignedUrlRequest, we provided an empty string for the bucket.
This was working great.
With the V2 API, we don't see how to generate such a presigned url. I tried the `endpointOverride` method on my `S3Presigner.builder` but in that case I get an url like `https://bucket-name/bucket-name/object-key`. So the aws server answer is `key does not exist` because the key is understood as `bucket-name/object-key`. It is not possible to provide an empty string for the bucket name to `GetObjectPresignRequest.builder` because the key is provided via the `GetObjectRequest` who must know the bucket name.